# Existence of a certain Morse function

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, morse-theory

Let $\mathbb{B}^4=\{(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4): x_1^2+x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2\leq 1\}$ be the closed unit 4-ball.  Consider first the Morse function
$$
f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)=\frac{1}{2}\left(x_1^2+x_2^2-x_3^2-x_4^2\right)
$$
and, for $t\in [-1,1]$ let
$$\Omega_t=\{x\in \mathbb{B}: f(x)\leq t\} \mbox{ and } \omega_t=\{x\in \partial \mathbb{B}: f(x)\leq t\}.
$$
Likewise, set
$$
\Sigma_t=\{x\in \mathbb{B}: f(x)=t\} \mbox{ and } \sigma_t=\{x\in \partial\mathbb{B}: f(x)\leq t\}.
$$
Observe that for $t\neq 0$, $\Sigma_t$ is a smooth hypersurface with boundary a torus $\sigma_t$.  Moreover, the radial projection may $\Pi:\Omega_t\to \omega_t$ is continuous for $t\in [-1,0)$ (and is continuous on the complementary sets when $t\in (0,1]$).

As each $\sigma_t$ is in same isotopy class we can pick  generators, $\gamma_t^1, \gamma_t^2$ of $\pi_1(\sigma_t)$ labeled so $\gamma_t^1$ is contractible in $\omega_t$ and $\gamma_t^2$ is not.

It's not hard to see (use the radial projection) that for $t\in [-1,0)$, $\gamma_t^1$ is contractible in $\Sigma_t$ while $\gamma_t^2$ is not, whereas for $t\in (0,1]$, $\gamma_t^2$ is contractible in $\Sigma_t$ while $\gamma_t^1$ is not.  When $t=0$ both $\gamma_0^1$ and $\gamma_0^2$ are contractible (and I guess this is how the "switch" takes place).

My question:  Is it possible to find a new Morse function $g$ on $\mathbb{B}^4$ with level sets $\Gamma_t$ so that

1. $\Sigma_{\pm 1}=\Gamma_{\pm 1}=\{g=\pm 1\}$
2. For all $t\in [-1,1]$, $\sigma_t=\{x\in \partial \mathbb{B}: g=t\}$
3. $0$ is a regular value of $g$ and $\Gamma_0$ has the property that $\gamma_0^1$ and $\gamma_0^2$ are both not contractible in $\Gamma_0$.

This means there would be critical points in $(-1,0)$ and $(0,1)$.  The difference with the first Morse function is that the ``switch" happens in the opposite way.

I apologize if this is too simple for this site, it's outside my area of expertiese.

Comment: Are you merely asking about the existence or would you be looking for a concrete, explicit description of the function?

Comment: @LeoMoos I don't need anything explicit.  Just existence along with a description of the critical points.  This is mostly to help build some intuition (so some handwavy description of what was happening would also be appreciated).